# get url segment relative to parent route

Tags: angular

In an Angular 11 app with a nested routing config, I want to know what the url is relative to the parent route.

e.g. if my route config is

```js
{
'car/:id', children: [{ path: 'tyres', CarTyreComponent }],
}
```

and the user is at **car/5/tyres**, the answer would be `"tyres"`.

Additionally, I want to be able update and access the value in a template so that I can highlight the **tyres** section like so:

```js
[ngClass]="if this.router.url.startsWith('tyres') ? 'active' : ''"
```

But the above example no longer works when you nest it, and I seem mired in subscribable and non-subscribable options of `ActivatedRoute` and `Router`.

What does work, but seems to be an error-prone approach, is this:

```js
[ngClass]="this.router.url.split('/')[3] === 'tyres' ? 'active' : ''"
```

Any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get an url segment from a child component it suppost to be:
In your `component.ts`:

```js
urlToCheck$$: Subject<string> = new Subject();

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute){
  this._route.parent?.url.subscribe( url => this.urlToCheck$$.next(url[0].path) )`
```

In html:

```html
[ngClass]="(urlToCheck$$ | async) === 'tyres' ? 'active' : ''"
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me: I added a log line to the subscription but it only logs once even as I browse around (and then it logs an empty string). I have 2 additional Qs: why do you use a `Subject` and why do you initialise in the `constructor` rather than `NgOnInit`?